# Arduino Webserver Update

Tags: javascript, arduino, webserver, ethernet

I have a small tidbit of code for my webserver on my arduino connected to an ethernet shield:

```
client.println("<html><head><title>ArduServ</title></head><body>");
client.print("Current Temperature: ");client.println(getTMP());
client.println("<form method=get>Input:<input type=text size=25 name=inp><input type=submit value=submit></form>");
client.println("</body></html>");
```

Is there a way I can update the temperature using javascript so that I don't have to redraw the page every second?  I can just change the temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not use the Arduino as an HTTP server for a couple of reasons.

1. **Performance** - as a micro controller, you have limited resources. Serving all of the headers and content can be expensive if you want the interaction to be real time.
2. **Manageability** - as I'm sure you're aware, it's really frustrating having to manage the source of the web page through strings in double quotes on multiple lines like that.

## The Solution

I've found that the most effective way to make a web controller interface for an Arduino is to host the page somewhere on your computer locally or even on a server if you have one. Then, make the Arduino a web socket server instead of HTTP server.

This will allow you to easily communicate using the `WebSocket` class in JavaScript, while not having to worry about the overhead of hosting the web content.

I've used **[this](https://github.com/brandenhall/Arduino-Websocket)** web socket server implementation for Arduino and it works great.

Here's a basic example based on what you showed us.

## Arduino

Assuming `ethernet` is an `EthernetServer`, and `socket` is a `WebSocketServer`.

```
// initialize the ethernet and socket server in setup() here ...

void loop(void)
{
    EthernetClient client = ethernet.available();

    if (client.connected() && socket.handshake(client))
    {
        while (client.connected())
        {
            String response;

            // add the temperature to the response 
            response += getTMP();

            // send the response to the JavaScript interface
            socket.sendData(response);

            // update every 250 milliseconds
            delay(250);
        }
    }

    // wait to let the client fully disconnect
    delay(100);
}
```

## JavaScript

```
// assuming you have something like <div id="temperature"></div> in the document
var temperature = document.getElementById('temperature');

// whatever IP that was assigned to the EthernetServer
var ip = '192.168.0.99';

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://'+ ip);

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    // update the temperature text
    temperature.innerHTML = e.data;
};
```

You can find more information about JavaScript web sockets [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications).

Comment: How do I initialize the WebSocketServer and what do I have to include to get it?

Comment: Download the master repository [here](https://github.com/brandenhall/Arduino-Websocket/archive/master.zip), then move it to your Documents/Arduino/libraries/ folder. You can open one of the example projects in the Arduino IDE from `File > Examples`. There isn't actually any initalization needed for the Web Socket though, only the Ethernet server.